# Selecting dates from maintable that are between two dates, that located in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i have two tables. one is the mainTable wit a lot of dates. and the other is a the rangeTable that has eventStart and eventEnd dates. so what i need is to use the rangeTable with the mainTable together and get all dates with the dates between the start and end date.

this is the table with all the dates

```
mainTable
2014-01-01 00:01:00 
2014-01-01 00:02:00 
2014-01-01 00:03:00 
2014-01-01 00:04:00 
2014-01-02 00:01:00 
2014-01-02 00:02:00 
2014-01-03 00:01:00 
2014-01-03 00:05:00
```

this is the table with the starting and ending ranges

```
rangeTable
event      date
start      2014-01-01 00:00:00 
end        2014-01-01 00:03:00 
start      2014-01-02 00:00:00 
end        2014-01-02 00:05:00 
start      2014-01-03 00:00:00 
end        2014-01-03 00:06:00
```

the result may look like this

```
event      date
start      2014-01-01 00:00:00
between    2014-01-01 00:01:00
between    2014-01-01 00:02:00
between    2014-01-01 00:03:00
end        2014-01-01 00:03:00 
start      2014-01-02 00:00:00
between    2014-01-02 00:01:00
between    2014-01-02 00:02:00
end        2014-01-02 00:05:00
start      2014-01-03 00:00:00
between    2014-01-03 00:01:00
between    2014-01-03 00:02:00
between    2014-01-03 00:05:00
end        2014-01-03 00:06:00
```

Thanks to everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
select * from mainTable m left join rangeTable r on m.date between r.start_date  and r.end_date
```

Comment: there is no field like end_date or start_date field. there are dates that have start event and end event. i need to list the date with start event and the date with the end event and between the dates that are between these dates